# piping to variables

Tags: shell, pipe, scripting

```
cut -d" " -f2 ${2} | $callsTo
```

hello, can somebody please explain can I pipe the result of cut to variable callsTo, and how will it be stored, as the string or list?

Comment: Are you trying to execute the command named by callsTo, or are you trying to assign to callsTo the value consisting of the output of cut?  I think you are trying to ask the latter, in which case pipes are irrelevant.  You want callsTo=$( cut -d' ' -f2 $2 )

Comment: @William Pursell: can I do this in C-shell?

Comment: csh: `set callsTo=\`cut -d" " -f2 ${2}\`, however: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Answer (score 0):

It will call the command stored in `$callsTo` and send the standard output of `cut` to the standard input of said command as a string.

Comment: how can store the result of cut in the variable callsTo?

Comment: If ${2} is not quoted it has to be a filename.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
cut -d" " -f2 ${2} | {
  read callsTo
}
```

You will have to keep subsequent references to `callsTo` within the brackets.